# How to read mail text in mail listener 2?

Tags: protractor

conf.js

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener2");
        var mailListener = new MailListener({

            username: "*****@office365.com",
            password: "******",
            host: "outlook.office365.com",
            port: 993, // imap port
            tls: true,
            fetchUnreadOnStart: true,
            tlsOptions: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
            mailbox: "INBOX",
            searchFilter: "UNSEEN",
            markSeen: true
        });

        mailListener.on("server:connected", function () {
            console.log("imapConnected");
        });

        mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function () {
            console.log("imapDisconnected");
        });

        (function () {
            var count = 0;
            mailListener.on("mail", function (mail, seqno, attributes) {
                var mailuid = attributes.uid,
                    toMailbox = 'Inbox',
                    i = ++count;
                if (i > 1) {
                    mailListener.stop(); // start listening
                    return;
                }
                console.log('email parsed', {
                    i: i,
                    subject: mail.subject,
                    from: mail.from,
                    text:mail.text,
                    seqno: seqno,
                    uid: attributes.uid,
                    attributes: attributes
                });
                expect(mail.subject).toEqual("FW: Secure One-Time-Password for Account Login");

                var pattern = new RegExp(/Please use (\w+)/g);
                var regCode = pattern.exec(mail.text)[1];
                console.log(regCode);

                console.log('attempting to mark msg read/seen');
                mailListener.imap.addFlags(mailuid, '\\Seen', function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('error marking message read/SEEN');
                        return;
                    }

                    //console.log('moving ' + (seqno || '?') + ' to ' + toMailbox);
                    //mailListener.imap.move(mailuid, toMailbox, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('error moving message');
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log('moved ' + (seqno || '?'), mail.subject);
                    });


                });
            });
        })

        ();
        mailListener.start(); // start listening

        setTimeout(function () {
            mailListener.stop(); // start listening
        }, 60 * 1000);
```

I am reading all the details except text and the text is in html table format.

Instead of text i am getting undefined message.If needed i will add html code also.

If i am forwarding the same mail to gmail from office 365 and reading the mail from gmail i am able to get text.

Error:

```
 subject: 'test mail',
  from: [ { address: 'otp@gmail.com', name: 'gmail.com' } ],
  body: undefined,
  seqno: 2,
  uid: 18,
  attributes: 
   { date: 2017-06-14T16:22:06.000Z,
     flags: [ '\\Seen' ],
     uid: 18,
     modseq: '3914',
     'x-gm-labels': [],
     'x-gm-msgid': '1570197813730673685',
     'x-gm-thrid': '1570197813730673685' } }
[21:56:13] E/launcher - Cannot read property '1' of null
[21:56:13] E/launcher - TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

Comment: alecxe ...please look into this question?

Comment: Where do you have this mail catching code? How do you configure your mailistener in the protractor config? How do you check the emails in your test? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Added conf code..please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

I see that this is an old issue, but I am facing the same problem and using the nearly the [same function](https://gist.github.com/yzorg/11307678).

I want to get the content of the e-mail with a link and the email is in HTML. So: **`mail.text`** doesn't and won't work in this case.

Solution is really simple and it works for me straight forward: **`mail.html`**